# How to fix checkboxes auto random selection by scrolling listview, and also shows java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 10

Tags: android-checkbox

Hi i'm new to android and doing custom listview with checkbox, in that i'm facing random selection of another list item checkbox while scrolling. I have gone through some threads but didn't solve my problem. Pls help me out from this. Here is my custom adapter
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.app.AlertDialog;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.content.DialogInterface;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.CheckBox;
            import android.widget.CompoundButton;
            import android.widget.ListView;
            import android.widget.TextView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

```
            public class ViewRecord extends Activity {

                DataBaseHelper db;
                ListView listView;
                Button delAll, more, setTime;
                ListAdapter list;
                CheckBox check;
                boolean checks = false;

                ArrayList<Contacts> arrayContacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.records);
                    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
                    delAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
                    more = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addMore);
                    setTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTime);
                    check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                    loadlist();

            //      For adding more contacts to BlockList       
                    more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ViewRecord.this, ContactList.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });

            //      For selecting the whole Records to delete.....
                            check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    list = new ListAdapter(getBaseContext());
                                    checks = !checks;
                                    for (int count =0; count<arrayContacts.size(); count++){
                                    listView.setAdapter(list);
                                    list.mCheckStates.put(count, checks);
                                    list.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
            //                      check.toggle();
                                }
                            });
                }

                private void loadlist() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        list = new ListAdapter(this);
                        listView.setAdapter(list);
                        //listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
                        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


                }

                @Override
                protected void onResume() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onResume();

                    arrayContacts.clear();
                    // Reading DataBase Contacts.
                    db = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    db.getWritableDatabase();
                    ArrayList<Contacts> arrayStor = db.getContacts();

                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayStor.size(); i++) {
                        String Id = arrayStor.get(i).getContactId();
                        String Name = arrayStor.get(i).getContactName();
                        String Number = arrayStor.get(i).getContactNumber();

                        Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
                        contacts.setContactId(Id);
                        contacts.setContactName(Name);
                        contacts.setContactNumber(Number);

                        arrayContacts.add(contacts);
                    }

            //      listView.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));
                    db.close();
                }

                private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

                    private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
                    LayoutInflater inflater;
                    ViewHolder viewHolder;
                    CheckBox cb;

                    public ListAdapter(Context context) {
                        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(arrayContacts.size());
                        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getCount() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return arrayContacts.size();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getItem(int position) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return position;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long getItemId(int position) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return position;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (convertView == null) {
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
                            cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkox);

                             cb.setTag(position);
                             cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
                             cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

                            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtdisplaypname);

                            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                        } else {
                            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                        }

                        viewHolder.txtName.setText(arrayContacts.get(position).getContactName().trim());

                        delAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                ViewRecord.this);
                        alertbox.setCancelable(true);
                        alertbox.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ?");
                        alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                            int arg1) {

                                        if(check.isChecked()==true){
                                            db.emptyRecords();
                                            check.toggle();
                                            ViewRecord.this.onResume();
                                        }else
                                        {
                                        for(int i = 0; i < arrayContacts.size(); i++){
                                               {
                                               if(mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                                               {         
                                                 db.RemoveRecord(arrayContacts.get(i).getContactId().trim(), "", "");
                                                 System.out.println("The contact name and id is :" + arrayContacts.get(i).getContactId() + arrayContacts.get(i).getContactName());
                                                ViewRecord.this.onResume();
                                                    }

                                               }
                                               }

                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Records Deleted...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        db.close();
                                    }
                                    }

                                });
                        alertbox.setNegativeButton("No",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                            int arg1) {
                                    }
                                });
                        alertbox.show(); 
                        db.close();
                            }


                        });

                        setTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                ArrayList<String> contactName = new ArrayList<String>();
                                ArrayList<String> contactNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for(int i = 0; i < arrayContacts.size(); i++)
                                   {
                                   if(mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                                   {        

                                   //   For sending contact names to schedule
                                    contactName.add(arrayContacts.get(i).getContactName());
                                    contactNumber.add(arrayContacts.get(i).getContactNumber()) ;
                                   }         
                                   }                     
                                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Time_Settings.class);
                                    sendIntent.putExtra("contactName", contactName);
                                    sendIntent.putExtra("contactNumber", contactNumber);
            //                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contactName + contactNumber, 0).show();
                                    startActivity(sendIntent);
                            }
                        });



                        return convertView;
                    }

                    public boolean isChecked(int position) {

                     return mCheckStates.get(position, checks);

                    }

                       public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                           mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
                           notifyDataSetChanged();

                       }

                       public void toggle(int position) {
                           setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

                       }
                   @Override
                   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                           boolean isChecked) {
                     mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);      
                   }

                }

                private class ViewHolder {
                    TextView txtName;
                }
            }
                }
```

Comment: hi guys i have a problem in my listview, by scrolling listview it auto selects checkboxes, plz see my code what is the problem in the code?????

Comment: I found the answer, delete braces and avoid reusing of views...

Answer (score 0):

Here i did a view reusing thats why it does auto checking checkboxes, just remove the braces and else part from getView this solved my problem

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer. When it is possible.